# Linear Mixed models: show that one paramter has an effect on outcome with two affecting parameters

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, mixed-random-variable

I have a serie of analysis on 5 different specimens, with 2 different modifying parameters and one `outcome`. Both parameters have an effect on the outcome. My goal is to show that `parameter_two` has an effect on the `outcome` (assuming outcome one constant). With the following code, I can show that it does indeed have a significant effect but it does not take into account the fact that `parameter_one` also have an effect. Do I have to run three linear mixed effect models (each for parameter one `1.0`, `2.0` and `3.0`) or is there a way to run only one model taking into account the fact the `parameter_one` changes and eventually being able to show that `parameter_two` has indeed an effect on the `outcome` (using the `nlme` package instead of `lme4` would be also fine).

Here is the code with synthetic data:

```
library(lme4)
library(broom)

###############################################
############# Synthetic data ##################
df = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5*9, ncol = 0))
df[,"ID"] = c(
        rep("specimen_01",9), 
        rep("specimen_02",9),
        rep("specimen_03",9), 
        rep("specimen_04",9), 
        rep("specimen_05",9)
)

df[,"parameter_one"] = c(
        rep(
            c(rep("1.0",3), 
            rep("2.0",3), 
            rep("3.0",3)),
            5)
)

df[,"parameter_two"] = c( 
        rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 15)
)
df[,"outcome"] = c( 
        rep(c(30,35,40,35,40,45,40,45,50), 5)
)

for (idx in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  df[idx,"outcome"] = df[idx,"outcome"] + runif(1, -3,3)
}
print(df)
###############################################


###############################################
############ linear models ####################
lmm_model = lmer('outcome~ parameter_two + (1|ID)', REML=FALSE, data = df)
lmm_modellist = coef(lmm_model)
LRT_model = tidy(drop1(lmm_model,test="Chisq"))
print(lmm_model)
print(LRT_model)
###############################################
```

Here is the output:

```
Loading required package: Matrix
Warning messages:
1: package ‘broom’ was built under R version 4.0.2
2: The package `ellipsis` (>= 0.3.2) is required as of rlang 1.0.0.
3: replacing previous import ‘ellipsis::check_dots_unnamed’ by ‘rlang::check_dots_unnamed’ when loading ‘tibble’
4: replacing previous import ‘ellipsis::check_dots_used’ by ‘rlang::check_dots_used’ when loading ‘tibble’
5: replacing previous import ‘ellipsis::check_dots_empty’ by ‘rlang::check_dots_empty’ when loading ‘tibble’
6: replacing previous import ‘ellipsis::check_dots_unnamed’ by ‘rlang::check_dots_unnamed’ when loading ‘pillar’
7: replacing previous import ‘ellipsis::check_dots_used’ by ‘rlang::check_dots_used’ when loading ‘pillar’
8: replacing previous import ‘ellipsis::check_dots_empty’ by ‘rlang::check_dots_empty’ when loading ‘pillar’
            ID parameter_one parameter_two  outcome
1  specimen_01           1.0             a 32.63216
2  specimen_01           1.0             b 34.20745
3  specimen_01           1.0             c 38.02290
4  specimen_01           2.0             a 34.20114
5  specimen_01           2.0             b 39.35347
6  specimen_01           2.0             c 42.33355
7  specimen_01           3.0             a 42.72540
8  specimen_01           3.0             b 44.57404
9  specimen_01           3.0             c 48.46312
10 specimen_02           1.0             a 27.50748
11 specimen_02           1.0             b 34.81480
12 specimen_02           1.0             c 40.37659
13 specimen_02           2.0             a 33.50029
14 specimen_02           2.0             b 42.58096
15 specimen_02           2.0             c 42.56689
16 specimen_02           3.0             a 41.55095
17 specimen_02           3.0             b 42.30466
18 specimen_02           3.0             c 50.92431
19 specimen_03           1.0             a 27.73878
20 specimen_03           1.0             b 33.16451
21 specimen_03           1.0             c 38.22694
22 specimen_03           2.0             a 33.49094
23 specimen_03           2.0             b 39.22459
24 specimen_03           2.0             c 46.68019
25 specimen_03           3.0             a 38.88184
26 specimen_03           3.0             b 44.66432
27 specimen_03           3.0             c 49.38164
28 specimen_04           1.0             a 28.03027
29 specimen_04           1.0             b 32.00285
30 specimen_04           1.0             c 38.92150
31 specimen_04           2.0             a 37.68010
32 specimen_04           2.0             b 40.87556
33 specimen_04           2.0             c 47.90651
34 specimen_04           3.0             a 40.14389
35 specimen_04           3.0             b 44.29567
36 specimen_04           3.0             c 52.62963
37 specimen_05           1.0             a 32.11252
38 specimen_05           1.0             b 34.25991
39 specimen_05           1.0             c 40.13325
40 specimen_05           2.0             a 35.91150
41 specimen_05           2.0             b 38.69821
42 specimen_05           2.0             c 47.61566
43 specimen_05           3.0             a 39.00830
44 specimen_05           3.0             b 45.65790
45 specimen_05           3.0             c 48.06335
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
Warning message:
In tidy.anova(drop1(lmm_model, test = "Chisq")) :
  The following column names in ANOVA output were not recognized or transformed: npar, LRT, Pr.Chi.
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: outcome ~ parameter_two + (1 | ID)
   Data: df
      AIC       BIC    logLik  deviance  df.resid
 276.9244  285.9577 -133.4622  266.9244        40
Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 0.000
 Residual             4.697
Number of obs: 45, groups:  ID, 5
Fixed Effects:
   (Intercept)  parameter_twob  parameter_twoc
        35.008           4.371           9.809
convergence code 0; 0 optimizer warnings; 1 lme4 warnings
# A tibble: 2 x 5
  term           npar   AIC   LRT     Pr.Chi.
  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1 <none>           NA  277.  NA   NA
2 parameter_two     2  298.  24.7  0.00000442
```

**EDIT**

I tried the code proposed in the answer. But I don't get a p value in the result of the anova. Why is that?

Here is the code:

```
library(broom)
library(lme4)


###############################################
############# Synthetic data ##################
df = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 5*9, ncol = 0))
df[,"ID"] = c(
        rep("specimen_01",9), 
        rep("specimen_02",9),
        rep("specimen_03",9), 
        rep("specimen_04",9), 
        rep("specimen_05",9)
)

df[,"parameter_one"] = c(
        rep(
            c(rep("1.0",3), 
            rep("2.0",3), 
            rep("3.0",3)),
            5)
)

df[,"parameter_two"] = c( 
        rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 15)
)
df[,"outcome"] = c( 
        rep(c(30,35,40,35,40,45,40,45,50), 5)
)

for (idx in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  df[idx,"outcome"] = df[idx,"outcome"] + runif(1, -3,3)
}

lmm_model1<-lmer(outcome~parameter_two+parameter_one+(1|ID), REML=F, data=df)

summary(lmm_model1)
LRT_model1<-tidy(drop1(lmm_model1,test="Chisq"))

LRT_model1
anova(lmm_model1)
```

Here is the output

````
Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood  ['lmerMod']
Formula: outcome ~ parameter_two + parameter_one + (1 | ID)
   Data: df

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid
   182.2    194.9    -84.1    168.2       38

Scaled residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max
-1.8516 -1.0187  0.1008  0.6013  2.0608

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID       (Intercept) 0.00     0.000
 Residual             2.46     1.568
Number of obs: 45, groups:  ID, 5

Fixed effects:
                 Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)       29.1568     0.5228  55.773
parameter_twob     5.3034     0.5727   9.261
parameter_twoc    10.2280     0.5727  17.860
parameter_one2.0   5.8184     0.5727  10.160
parameter_one3.0  10.7034     0.5727  18.690

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) prmtr_twb prmtr_twc pr_2.0
paramtr_twb -0.548
paramtr_twc -0.548  0.500
parmtr_n2.0 -0.548  0.000     0.000
parmtr_n3.0 -0.548  0.000     0.000     0.500
convergence code: 0
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular

boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular
Warning message:
In tidy.anova(drop1(lmm_model1, test = "Chisq")) :
  The following column names in ANOVA output were not recognized or transformed: npar, LRT, Pr.Chi.
# A tibble: 3 x 5
  term           npar   AIC   LRT   Pr.Chi.
  <chr>         <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1 <none>           NA  182.  NA   NA
2 parameter_two     2  272.  94.1  3.71e-21
3 parameter_one     2  276.  97.8  5.87e-22
Analysis of Variance Table
              npar Sum Sq Mean Sq F value
parameter_two    2 784.95  392.47  159.56
parameter_one    2 861.40  430.70  175.11
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is a simple matter of having both parameters in the model:

````
    lmm_model1<-lmer(outcome~parameter_two+parameter_one+(1|ID), REML=F, data=df)

    summary(lmm_model1)
    Linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood . t-tests use Satterthwaite's 
    method ['lmerModLmerTest']
    Formula: outcome ~ parameter_two + parameter_one + (1 | ID)
    Data: df
     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
    170.1    182.8    -78.1    156.1       38 
    Scaled residuals: 
      Min      1Q   Median      3Q     Max 
    -2.0783 -0.8230  0.1158  0.6424  1.9807 
    Random effects:
    Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
    ID       (Intercept) 0.2112   0.4595  
    Residual             1.7320   1.3160  
    Number of obs: 45, groups:  ID, 5
    Fixed effects:
                   Estimate Std.   Error     df t value Pr(>|t|)    
    (Intercept)       29.9003     0.4844 29.0499  61.722  < 2e-16 ***
    parameter_twob     4.3996     0.4805 40.0000   9.155 2.31e-11 ***
    parameter_twoc    10.2205     0.4805 40.0000  21.268  < 2e-16 ***
    parameter_one2.0   4.9581     0.4805 40.0000  10.317 7.78e-13 ***
    parameter_one3.0  10.5784     0.4805 40.0000  22.013  < 2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
    Correlation of Fixed Effects:
                (Intr) prmtr_twb prmtr_twc pr_2.0
    paramtr_twb -0.496                           
    paramtr_twc -0.496  0.500                    
    parmtr_n2.0 -0.496  0.000     0.000          
    parmtr_n3.0 -0.496  0.000     0.000     0.500

    LRT_model1<-tidy(drop1(lmm_model1,test="Chisq"))
    Warning message:
    In tidy.anova(drop1(lmm_model1, test = "Chisq")) :
    The following column names in ANOVA output were not recognized or transformed: 
    NumDF, DenDF

    LRT_model1
    # A tibble: 2 x 7
    term          sumsq meansq NumDF DenDF statistic  p.value
    <chr>         <dbl>  <dbl> <int> <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
    1 parameter_two  788.   394.     2  40.0      228. 1.39e-22
    2 parameter_one  840.   420.     2  40.0      243. 4.31e-23

    anova(lmm_model1)
    Type III Analysis of Variance Table with Satterthwaite's method
                  Sum Sq Mean Sq NumDF DenDF F value    Pr(>F)    
    parameter_two 788.50  394.25     2    40  227.63 < 2.2e-16 ***
    parameter_one 840.37  420.18     2    40  242.61 < 2.2e-16 ***
    ---
    Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```
````

Comment: Many thanks for your answer @relativenewbie. I tried the code that you proposed in the answer. But I don't get a p value in the result of the anova. Why is that?

Comment: You need the lmerTest package. FYI REML=F is used when comparing several models, once you have decided on the "best" model you need to refit with REML. Also on this note, I use the cAIC4 package to select the best model using conditional AIC. Other useful packages for mixed models: performance, DHARMA and sjplot

Comment: Ok @relativenewbie. Many thanks for comments and answer